# Is it possible for Python C extension to efficiently get the call site information?

Tags: cpython

I am trying to marry CPython and .NET DLR. The later has a mechanism for fast dynamic dispatch based on actual parameter types at the call site, which I'd like to take advantage of. For example, suppose I have an overloaded function in C#, that I want to call from Python:

```
void Foo(int arg) {}
void Foo(string arg) {}
```

Then in Python I have a script like this:

```
Foo(42)      # line 1
Foo("Hello") # line 2
```

So in my C extension I am implementing `tp_call` for `Foo`. To be able to use the fast dispatch cache provided by DLR I need to get some value, that can be obtained quickly and uniquely identifies the call site (e.g. tells my `tp_call` which script line is being invoked). Is anything like that available?

The `PyFrameObject` returned by `PyEval_GetFrame` seems like it might do the trick, but it is poorly documented, so it is unclear which fields from it can be used. Is `PyFrame_GetLineNumber` the only supported available value?

Comment: I haven't even heard of the .NET DLR but, what is the information you need from the call site? You have the type (your `FooType` struct lets say) and the (positional) arguments that are passed along to `tp_call` in some `PyTupleObject`.

Comment: @DimitrisFasarakisHilliard ideally, I need the line of code (and the file too), which called `Foo`. I tried to make it clear in the question: this information allows to build a cache which overload of `Foo` was called per line of code. In the example above line 1 will always call `int` overload, and line 2 will always call `string` overload. See this blog for a more detailed explanation of the idea: https://www.jayconrod.com/posts/44/polymorphic-inline-caches-explained

Comment: `PyFrame_GetLineNumber` does seem to be the only option here. If you are working with the limited API, I can't see how you could get the filename though (another exported function `PyFrame_GetCode` returns the code but there's no functions for code objects that return its `co_filename` afaik). If you aren't working within the limited API, I guess you could get the `co_filename` from the code object returned from `PyFrame_GetCode`.